# How to initialize a field with more than one operation?

Tags: scala, constructor

```
class A (names: String*) {
  val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String]
}
```

I was wondering, how I can add the names of the names array from the primary constructor argument to the namesBuffer field when creating the object ?
Do I have to create an auxiliary construtor to do so or is there another way to tell Scala to do operations in the primary Constructor ?

Note: The example above is fictive, I just want to know, how I can tell the primary constructor to do some more operations than assigning fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As axel22's answer demonstrates, you can perform those operations anywhere in the body of the class.

But it is good practice IMO to initialize the field fully with a single expression.

When side effects are required, you can achieve this using curly braces to make a block, which is an expression having the value of the last line:

```
class A(names: String*) {
  val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = {
    val buffer = new ListBuffer[String]
    buffer ++= names
    buffer
  }
}
```

With this technique, you ensure that no other initialization logic accesses the value of `namesBuffer` before you have finished initializing that.

Answer (score 3):

Every statement in the body of the class definition becomes a part of the body of the default constructor.

In your example you can just do:

```
class A (names: String*) {
  val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String]
  namesBuffer ++= names
}
```

or shorter:

```
class A (names: String*) {
  val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String] ++= names
}
```

or:

```
class A (names: String*) {
  val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer[String](names: _*)
}
```

Comment: `val namesBuffer = new ListBuffer ++ names` works just as well, no type annotation required (although sometimes it's good practice on public members for readability)

Comment: For a public API it is good to be explicit, however you still don't need to repeat the type parameter on the right hand side: `val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(names: _*)`

Answer (score 0):

In Scala the entire class definition is effectively the default constructor, if that makes sense.

You can do something like this:

```
class A (names: String*) {
  val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String]
  namesBuffer.add(names)
}
```

You could also initialize the names buffer if it took a string array:

```
class A (names: String*) {
  val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String](names)
}
```

Comment: Your second suggestion does not work (or I do something wrong):
scala> class A(names: String*) {val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String](names)}
<console>:9: error: too many arguments for constructor ListBuffer: ()scala.colle
ction.mutable.ListBuffer[String]
       class A(names: String*) {val namesBuffer: ListBuffer[String] = new ListBu
ffer[String](names)}
                                                                      ^

Comment: That's why I said 'if' it took a string array. I stay away from mutable collections in scala so I'm not familiar with the ListBuffer api.